# How to find all the Quadratic residue of $x$?

Tags: prime-numbers, quadratic-residues

How can I efficiently find all the [Quadratic residue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) of some prime number $x$?

$$\{y ~\vert~ x^2 \equiv y \pmod{p}\}$$

In wiki they speak about some thing called `lifting`, by I am not sure how to use it.

> If the modulus n is a prime power n = pe, a solution may be found
>   modulo p and "lifted" to a solution modulo n using Hensel's lemma or
>   an algorithm of Gauss

Comment: Do you mean you want to find $\{z ~\vert~ \exists y~~ y^2 \equiv z \pmod{x}\}$ ?  Or are you asking how to find $\{y ~\vert~ y^2 \equiv x \pmod{p}\}$ ?

Comment: @DanielV edited

Comment: $\{y \mid x^2 \equiv y \pmod{p}\}$ (not one of Daniel's proposals) is just the set $\{x^2+kp\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}$.

Comment: Please double check what you wrote, it seems unlikely that this is what you are trying to calculate.  What your wrote is relatively trivial as Mr Makholm pointed out.

Comment: @DanielV you right, I got it wrong, but Henning Makholm answered what I asked. I asked a new question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145325/how-to-find-all-the-quadratic-residue-of-q). It's the way you got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find *all* of them, then simply computing $y^2 \bmod x$ for all $y$ between $0$ and $\frac{x-1}{2}$ will produce all of them, in some order, at a cost of one modular squaring per number being output. It's difficult to imagine how one could hope for a faster method than that.

Comment: Do you think "lifting" can make it better?

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman: I'm not sure what that is, and what kind of "better" would it make it?