# How to find all the Quadratic residues modulo $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, factoring, quadratic-residues

I want to implement [Sieve improvement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method#Sieve_improvement) for **Fermat's factorization method**.

For that I need your help answering: How to find all the Quadratic residues modulo $p$?

$$\{x ~\vert~ x^2 \equiv q \pmod{p}\}$$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm

Comment: @DanielV That algorithm searches for $x$ given $(q,p)$, while the OP is searching for all $q$ such that $\exists x$ giving $x^2\equiv q\pmod{p}$ for a specific given prime $p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I have misunderstood the question. But the obvious method is:

For $0 \le n \le \lfloor p/2\rfloor$, $n^2$ (mod $p$) is a quadratic residue mod $p$.

This generates all quadratic residues exactly once.

Comment: This is funny, a year after asking this I came to similar question again. Will this solution will work if $p$ is not a prime? This is part of a bigger question that I have, please tell me if it's not trivial, than I ask it officially. In my today's case I found some $k^2 - C \equiv 0 (\mod n)$ I want to find the smallest $i > 0$  such that $(k+i)^2 - C\equiv 0 (\mod n)$. P.S I am going to order that book you recommend me.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman: This is absolutely trivial! It's just a question of definitions. Think about it for a bit.

Comment: So $i =\sqrt{C \mod n}$? This would be half trivial for me

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman: I was answering your question "Will this solution work if $p$ is not prime?" As for your new question: if $k^2-C \equiv 0 \bmod n$, then $(k+i)^2-C \equiv (2k+i)i \bmod n$. So $i=n-2k$ is a solution; but finding the _smallest_ such $i$ might be difficult.

Comment: Where may I find a proof for the "obvious method"?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to find a [primitive root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) mod $p$.

If $g$ is a primitive root mod $p$, write $q = g^n$ and $x=g^k$.

Then the solutions of $x^2 \equiv q \bmod{p}$ correspond to the solutions of $2k \equiv n \bmod (p-1)$. This linear equation is easy to solve.

For example, take $p=31$. Then $g=3$ is a primitive root.

Take $q=19$. Then $n=4$ and $2k \equiv 4 \bmod 30$ gives $k=2$ and $k=17$, which gives $x=9$ and $x=22$.

Take $q=17$. Then $n=7$. But $2k \equiv 7\bmod 30$ has no solution and so $x^2 \equiv 17 \bmod 31$ has no solution.

If $q$ is not given and you only want to know the squares mod $p$, then they are $g^{n}$ with $n$ even.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand this. Can you please explain what primitive root is? May be you can provide an example

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman, see my edited answer.

Comment: The idea is not to pick up $q$, but to find all the possible $q$ for given $p$. For example for $p=4$ the solution is $\{0,1\}$

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman A primitive root modulo $n$ is $g$ such that $\text{ord}_n{g}=\phi(n)$ (order of $\mathbb Z_n$), i.e. $g^k$ can be congruent to any residue class modulo $n$. Such a $g$ exists iff $n=2,4,p^m,2p^m$ for some odd prime, $m\in\mathbb N$. Hence $g$ here exists (since $p^1$) and you can then write $q\equiv g^n\pmod{p}, x\equiv g^k\pmod{p}$ for some $n,k\in\mathbb N$. Then $g^{2k}\equiv g^{n}\pmod{p}$. But $g^{a}\equiv g^{a\pmod{p-1}}\pmod{p}$, $\forall a\in\mathbb N$, since $g^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Thus $2k\equiv n\pmod{p-1}\iff k\equiv n\cdot 2^{-1}\pmod{\frac{p-1}{2}}$.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman I've edited your question since because of your confusing wording Ihf solved the wrong problem. He found all the possible $x$ for a given pair $(q,p)$, while you are searching for all $q$ such that $\exists x$ giving $x^2\equiv q\pmod{p}$ for a specific given prime $p$.